# How to get one string value from Mega ADK and use it in eclipse in doing an Android Application

Tags: android, arduino, nfc, adk

I have an Android Tablet, Arduino ADK, and an NFC shield. I can read tags using the NFC shield on Arduino ADK.

Now I just need to get that tag and use it in programing my android application so when i upload the right sketch on my arduino and the application on my android device and connect them via USB, they can work hand in hand.